# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for UITableVewCell custom cell class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, null, option-type

When running code for a table view, I am trying to instantiate a custom cell and fill it with values and everything seems to work find until it gets to putting values into the outlets.

**Couple notes :**

1. I know that the preferred method here is to use
   "tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" however in this
   situation I am taking a different route.
2. Also, outlets in the custom cell are hooked up to the corresponding cell in the story board.
3. Appropriate delegates are setup.

Thanks in advance.

```
class FavoritesPropertyViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellPropertyImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellRoomsValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellSpaceValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellPriceRangeValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellCityStateZipValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellAddressValue: UILabel!

}
```

---

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

var newPropertyCell: FavoritesPropertyViewCell = FavoritesPropertyViewCell()

newPropertyCell.cellRoomsValue.text = "2 rooms"
newPropertyCell.cellSpaceValue.text = "2000 sqft"
newPropertyCell.cellPriceRangeValue.text = "20,000"
newPropertyCell.cellAddressValue.text = "123 that address" 
newPropertyCell.cellCityStateZipValue.text = "Knoxvegas TN 37777"

return newPropertyCell
}
```

---

[image: The variables shown have values in them.]

Lastly, the error : 
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: Most likely one of your outlets is not properly wired up from IB.  That causes it to be nil, and since you're using forced optionals in the declaration, it will crash.

Comment: I'm guessing that newPropertyValue.cellRoomsValue is nil.

Comment: try 
`var newPropertyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newPropertyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FavoritesPropertyViewCell()`

Comment: Thanks Peter but as specified, I specifically don't want to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Comment: Thanks RehcsifMit but the outlets are connected properly.

Answer (score 3):

`var newPropertyCell: FavoritesPropertyViewCell = FavoritesPropertyViewCell()`

None of the outlets are being set because no communication with storyboard(xib) is happening here, you just instantiate the type. Therefore all of them are nil.

The right approach is to use `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, which will load UI from storyboard (registered xib) for you.

Comment: As I stated, I get what the right way is, but is there another way that is less "right"?

Comment: Then what you are looking for is how to instantiate table view cells from storyboard. I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Or move them to xibs and do what @abdullah described in his answer.

Comment: In any chase, fixing whatever prevents you from doing this the right way would be a better time investment in my opinion.

Comment: I understand that, and I know the suggested right way and why. Without getting into why I want to do it a different way, what I am asking is whether there is a different way (not whether it is the right way).

Comment: My last comment was just a suggestion, read the two above where I try to point you in the direction of solution for your problem.

Comment: I am thinking I may need to move them to xibs.  I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `var newPropertyCell: FavoritesPropertyViewCell = FavoritesPropertyViewCell()`, your outlets are not linked. All your `@IBOutlet`are nil.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I had suspected but I had hoped that connecting custom cell to the IBOutlets in the class would have bridged that issue.  Evidently not.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to instantiate your cell:

```
var cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("<Your cell xib name>", owner: nil, options: nil).first as FavoritesPropertyViewCell
```

When you instantiate just using FavoritesPropertyViewCell() it will load the nib and make necessary outlet connections but here just a class instance will be created.

You need to load nib in order to get the full functionality.

Comment: Thanks Abdullah.  So far your answer is the closest to what I am asking for however this isn't a xib, this is a custom cell with an identifier.  How might it look to load that?

Comment: If is not linked with xib then how come you have @IBOutlets?

Comment: You can connect IBOutlets to objects within the storyboard so in this case, I have two different cells in the tableview and I use the identifier to determine which cell I want to use.  The cell view itselft is connected to the class holding the IBOutlet parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class in the file owner in the xib file matches the class you are trying to load.